# Multiple Docker containers with Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following setup:

- 1 machine with Docker installed
- 1 domain name (for example `mydomain.com`)
- 3 containers

  - Portainer (listening on port 9000)
  - Jupyter (listening on port 8888)
  - Nginx

The problem im having is proxying the request from outside (using the `nginx` container). So when im accessing `mydomain.com/juputer` should lead to the `jupyter` container and `mydomain.com/portainer` should lead to the `portainer` container. Accessing both containers from the local machine is fine.

I've managed to make the `prtainer` container accessible from outside but can't make it work for the other containers.

When accessing `portainer` via `mydomain.com/portainer` all links are redirected correctly (`mydomain.com/portainer/#/dashboard`, `mydomain.com/portainer/#/containers` etc) But when try to access `jupyter` container im getting 404 and the url is changed to `mydomain.com/tree?`. `tree?` is part of Jupyter but i was expecting the link to be `mydomain.com/jupyter/tree?`

I've tried few other configuration options in `nginx.conf` but nothing seems to work for me

Is this something that can be fixed from `Nginx` side or its application specific (should edit the configuration of the apps if possible)

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

#172.17.0.2 and 172.17.0.4 are the containers internal ip
#ips will be replaced by names in the future

upstream portainer {
    server 172.17.0.2:9000;
}

upstream jupyter {
    server 172.17.0.4:8888;
}   

server {
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;

    location /portainer/ {
        proxy_pass         http://portainer/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location /jupyter/ {
        proxy_pass         http://jupyter/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do the other 2 really need to be publicly exposed?

Comment: yep. All containers on this machine should be exposed.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy . This does essentially the proxying for you. The only container exposed is that one, which redirects locally based on the `-e VIRTUAL_HOST=xx.mydomain.xom` env variable of the other containers. I think it might be exactly what you're looking for, without having to configure everything yourself. But I don't know if it works for sub-folders of the URI or just complete subdomains...

Comment: I had a look at jwilder/nginx-proxy but dont think it works with sub-folders (only with sub domains). Found couple of other solutions (based on jwilder/nginx-proxy) which should work with sub-folders but they didnt worked quite well. Thats why ive reached a point to try and make it

Comment: Ended using sibdomains instefa of subfolders using  github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.